# Selenium (Python)- Webscraping verb-conjugation tables (Accessing web elements underneath '#document')

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, iframe, beautifulsoup

**Section 0: Introduction:**

This is my first webscraping project and I am not experienced in using selenium . I am trying to scrape arabic verb-conjugation tables from the website:
[Online Sarf Generator](https://sites.google.com/view/sarfgenerator/home)

Any help with the following probelem will be great.
Thank you.

**Section 1: The Problem:**

I am trying to webscrape from the following website:
[Online Sarf Generator](https://sites.google.com/view/sarfgenerator/home)

For doing this, I am trying to use Selenium.

I basically need to select the three root letters and the family from the four toggle menus as shown in the picture below:
[image]

After this, I have to click the 'Generate Sarf Table' button.

**Section 2: My Attempt:**

Here is my code:

```
#------------------ Just Setting Up the web_driver:
s = Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
# Set some selenium chrome options:
chromeOptions = Options()
# chromeOptions.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chromeOptions)
driver.get('https://sites.google.com/view/sarfgenerator/home')

# I switch the frame once:
iframe = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
# I switch the frame again:
iframe = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

This takes me to the frame within which the webelements that I need are located.

Now, I print the html to see where I am at:

```
print(BeautifulSoup(driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;"),'html.parser'))
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="userHtmlFrame" scrolling="yes">
</iframe>
<script>function loadGapi(){var loaderScript=document.createElement('script');loaderScript.setAttribute('src','https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?checkCookie=1');loaderScript.onload=function(){this.onload=function(){};loadGapiClient();};loaderScript.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==='complete'){this.onload();}};(document.head||document.body||document.documentElement).appendChild(loaderScript);}function updateUserHtmlFrame(userHtml,enableInteraction,forceIosScrolling){var frame=document.getElementById('userHtmlFrame');if(enableInteraction){if(forceIosScrolling){var iframeParent=frame.parentElement;iframeParent.classList.add('forceIosScrolling');}else{frame.style.overflow='auto';}}else{frame.setAttribute('scrolling','no');frame.style.pointerEvents='none';}clearCookies();clearStorage();frame.contentWindow.document.open();frame.contentWindow.document.write('<base target="_blank">'+userHtml);frame.contentWindow.document.close();}function onGapiInitialized(){gapi.rpc.call('..','innerFrameGapiInitialized');gapi.rpc.register('updateUserHtmlFrame',updateUserHtmlFrame);}function loadGapiClient(){gapi.load('gapi.rpc',onGapiInitialized);}if(document.readyState=='complete'){loadGapi();}else{self.addEventListener('load',loadGapi);}function clearCookies(){var cookies=document.cookie.split(";");for(var i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){var cookie=cookies[i];var equalPosition=cookie.indexOf("=");var name=equalPosition>-1?cookie.substr(0,equalPosition):cookie;document.cookie=name+"=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";document.cookie=name+"=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT ;domain=.googleusercontent.com";}}function clearStorage(){try{localStorage.clear();sessionStorage.clear();}catch(e){}}</script>
```

However, the actual html on the website looks like this:
[image]

**Section 3: The main problem with my approach:**

I am unable to access the anything #document contained within the iframe.

**Section 4: Conclusion:**

- Is there a possible solution that can fix my current approach to the problem?
- Is there any other way to solve the problem described in Section 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a lot of effort into structuring your question, so I couldn't not answer it, even if it meant double negation.
Here is how you can drill down into the iframe with content:
**EDIT: here is how you can select some options, click the button and access the results:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

url = 'https://sites.google.com/view/sarfgenerator/home'
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@aria-label="Custom embed"]')))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="innerFrame"]')))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userHtmlFrame"]')))

first_select = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//select[@id="root1"]'))))
second_select = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//select[@id="root2"]'))))
third_select = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//select[@id="root3"]'))))

first_select.select_by_visible_text("ج")
second_select.select_by_visible_text("ت")
third_select.select_by_visible_text("ص")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//button[@onclick="sarfGenerator(false)"]')))).click()
print('clicked')

result = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//p[@id="demo"]')))
print(result.text)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
clicked
جَتَّصَ      يُجَتِّصُ      تَجتِيصًا      مُجَتِّصٌ
جُتِّصَ      يُجَتَّصُ      تَجتِيصًا      مُجَتَّصٌ
جَتِّصْ       لا تُجَتِّصْ      مُجَتَّصٌ          Highlight Root Letters
```

Selenium setup is for Linux, you just have to observe the imports, and the part after defining the driver.
Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this. However, I do not just want the labels of the dropdown menus. I want to 'click' the dropdown menu for the three roots and then click the 'Generate Sarf Table button.'

Can you show me how to do that?

Again, thanks a lot for helping out a noob :)

Comment: There you go mate, I updated the response to show you how you can select various options from those dropdowns and click on the button. @MathWiz